# Backbone Fetch not by ID

Tags: backbone.js

is it possible to fetch on backbone, by a different attribute?

Now I can only fetch by ID which will return /url/IDVALUE
is is possible to do

```
      model.fetch({name:'VALUE'});
```

and then it will generate the /url/NAMEVALUE ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a workaround and I think you should use this just to do the fetch but I think it can work

change the IdAttributte and use the name,
then when you fetch your model the url will use the name attribute

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  idAttribute: "name"
});
```